# Iphone Receiving Errors in Organizer Console

Tags: iphone, console

When attempting to use the app I have developed I am receiving the following errors:

```
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p3b): unknown register number 59 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p3c): unknown register number 60 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p3d): unknown register number 61 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p3e): unknown register number 62 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p3f): unknown register number 63 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p40): unknown register number 64 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p41): unknown register number 65 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p42): unknown register number 66 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p43): unknown register number 67 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p44): unknown register number 68 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p45): unknown register number 69 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p46): unknown register number 70 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p47): unknown register number 71 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p48): unknown register number 72 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p49): unknown register number 73 requested
Sun Oct 18 17:49:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[316] <Error>: error: RNBRemote::HandlePacket_p(p4a): unknown register number 74 requested
```

Unfortunately I am not finding anything on google about RNBRemote or HandlePacket_p messages. Has anyone received anything like this before and what could be causing it? It crashes the app.

Thank You

Comment: Your best bet is to file a bug via http://bugreport.apple.com/  Prior to doing so, make sure you have the latest version of Xcode installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your build, or even throwing the whole build folder away. Also delete any copies from your iPhone and install again. Make sure you are using the correct provisioning profiles, configuration and target. It looks like Xcode is having trouble connecting to your app when trying to debug it. I've seen this kind of problem happening, and could always resolve it this way, though YMMV.